# How to Attack the Firebase Database Rules?

Tags: ios, firebase, security, websocket, sniffing

I'm working with Firebase for an iOS application. I'm trying to understand how strict my rules need to be, so am trying to attack them myself. My thinking is, if I can find ways of circumventing really lax rules (such as .read and .write are allowed, or simply require authorization) I can build more rules as needed.

I'm fairly confident in the security of my credentials, so an attacker would have to sniff traffic using a proxy, and somehow use their authorization token to make their own calls against the Firebase database. What method would a user be able to use to grab their authorization token (by sniffing proxy traffic, or otherwise) to make their own calls to the database? It seems the Firebase SDK on iOS uses websockets, and the tools for sniffing web traffic (like Charles Proxy) don't seem to easily support websocket sniffing for iOS, so should I be in the clear without any database rules in my app?

In short, is there a way I can act as a bad actor and attack my own database by hijacking my Firebase authorization token? If not, do I really need to worry about the database rules?

Comment: Per the answers, the fundamentals of Firebase rules are unrelated to packet sniffing, authorization tokens etc. One thing that may not be clear is Firebase rules are binary. Either you can or can't access a node; there's no 'lax rules'. However, your definition of lax may be different than mine. e.g. if you require authentication and only allow auth'd users whose favorite food is pizza to access the 'Best Pizza Restaurants' node then that's that. As you can see, rules are a much higher level than packets. Sniffing is a low level activity that falls into general security and not Firebase Rules.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the point (a bit).

Security rules can be used to limit what a particular user can do.  Whether or not that use obtains legitimate credentials is not your concern.  **There are many ways that a user can give up their credentials to an attacker**, and there's nothing you can do about it, so don't put effort into stopping that from happening.  If you are worried about sniffing or phishing, just know that it's out of your control, and **the user's device can give up every private piece of information if it's compromised**.  Just make sure that each user can do only what you allow, without respect to anything else.

Outside of per-user rules, you should only be concerned about what unauthenticated users can do in your database.  If you allow any unauthenticated reads or writes, you need to think about that carefully and write the rules carefully.  Ideally, you do not allow public writes except in very controlled situations.

Comment: I appreciate your post, and the principles behind it. Still, I’m trying to better understand the methods of attack for this specific scenario to evaluate and communicate the risk.

Comment: Sounds kind of broad for Stack Overflow.  If you want a discussion, may I recommend the firebase-talk Google group or the firebase Reddit?

Comment: Thanks, can crosspost there. More specifically: which attacks exist against the Firebase authorization and secure websockets used by the Firebase SDK on iOS which would warrant the addition of data rules as protection?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432298/1968911) said, it's worth looking at restricting what users can write to the database in terms of the object structure.

Personally I've used [Firebase Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) which simplifies the process.

If you want a user to write to their account object which contains `firstName` and `emailAddress` you could write the bolt markup as;

```
type Accounts {
  emailAddress: String,
  firstName: String
}

path /accounts/{uid} is Accounts {
  create() { auth != null && auth.uid == uid; }
  update() { auth != null && auth.uid == uid; }
}
```

This helps keep your data clean and restricts the user from breaking logic. If they have a flat `.write` access to their nodes, they can delete data, or create unstructured objects which can cause problems. Defining the model helps secure/maintain the integrity of the database.